# Can I make a shortcut of Google Sheets files in my Android phone?

Tags: google-sheets, android

I want to make a shortcut of Google Sheets file in my phone, so I want to click that file directly not through executing the Google Sheets app. However, although I know how to make a shortcut of Chrome web page in a phone, I can't make a shortcut of Google Sheets file. Please, help me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question about using Android. Try [android.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your Widgets section. Go to Drive in widgets and choose "Drive Shortcut". Choose the account to use (if necessary) then select the document or whatever you want.